# Set Jquery datepicker to previous value selected on modelstate error

Tags: c#, .net, jquery-ui, model-view-controller, jquery-ui-datepicker

We are using the JQuery UI datepicker on an MVC project to populate a hidden form field that forms part of our model. The problem we have is when a Modelstate error occurs and the user is returned back to the orginal form they submitted (with the values they selected pre-populated) the JQuery UI datepicker reverts to the current date. We need this to display the date that the user selected. How would we go about doing this?

HTML

```
    <div class="col-md-2">
         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Departure_Date, new { @class = "control-label required" })                 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div id="datepicker" class="dateDeparture"></div>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Departure_Date, new { id = "departureDate"})
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
$(".dateDeparture").datepicker({
    altField: "#departureDate",
    defaultDate: setDate,
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yyyy"
});

function setDate(){
   var date = $('#departureDate').value;
   if(date == ""){
       date = new Date();
   }
   return date;
}
```

As you can see above we try and get teh value of the hidden field and then use that to set the date on the datepicker but this does not work and we get the following error:

> TypeError: i.getTime is not a function
>   http://localhost:49438/scripts/jquery-ui.min.js Line 8

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`defaultDate` expects a string value, you're passing it a function.

You should try executing the function like:

```
$(".dateDeparture").datepicker({
    altField: "#departureDate",
    defaultDate: setDate(),
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yyyy"
});

function setDate(){
   var date = $('#departureDate').value;
   if(date == ""){
       date = new Date();
   }
   return date;
}
```